# The Taylor series and time complexity analysis

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I was just wondering, if an algorithm $A$ has a time complexity O$(2^n)$, since $2^n$ can be represented using a Taylor series, which is a polynomial, does this mean that $A$ has polynomial time complexity? Generalising even further, does this mean that any algorithm which has a time complexity O($f(n)$) where $f(n)$ has a corresponding Taylor series representation is also a polynomial time algorithm?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: If you define the term "polynomial" to include polynomials with *unbounded* degree (and thus infinite terms) then yes... but that's not usually the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2^n$ can be represented as a Taylor series, which is an *infinite sum* of polynomials. Notably, there is no single polynomial which is equal to $2^n$.

In general, since big-O lets us get rid of lower-degree terms in the polynomial, we can say that something has polynomial time (or space or whatever you're measuring) when it is $O(n^k)$ *for some fixed $k$*.

Since there's no *single* $k$ where $\forall n \ldotp O(2^n) = O(n^k)$, we say that $2^n$ is not polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you are confusing *Taylor series* and *Taylor polynomial*. $2^n$ can be represented as a *Taylor series*, which is an infinite series of polynomials (that is the limit of an infinite sequence of polynomials). When you cut off a *Taylor series* at some fixed degree, you get a *Taylor polynomial*, which is a polynomial. However, $2^n$ cannot be reasonably approximated by any polynomial, including a *Taylor polynomial*.